# VS2012 Error on setup on Windows 8 - Visual C++ 2012 x86 Minimum Runtime cannot be found

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, installation

I am getting a few errors trying to download the new VS2012. Its a fresh install of windows 8 (did the windows update).  I have tried not selecting all (no C++, lightswitch, blend, office tools)
I tried different mounting tools for the .ISO but no luck.  VS2010 is still working. Running x86.  [Log file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/75069700/logfile.txt)

Errors:

Critical: Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 x86 Minimum Runtime - 11.0.507 Cannot find the requested object.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Pre-Clean Tool  Cannot find the requested object

Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 x86 Additional Runtime - 11.0.507 Cannot find the requested object.

Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Core Libraries, Team Foundation Server 2012, Microsoft Framework 4.5 Multi-Targeting pack.... and a few other ones  cannot be found.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the iso file you downloaded is good? (non-corrupt) I'd like to suggest making sure the checksum for your ISO matches an expected value, but I can't find any officially published checksum values from Microsoft. If you can find someone with known good install media then you could generate a hash of that and verify yours matches that value

Comment: How do I check the checksum? I think it should be okay, my friend used it as well I believe

Comment: nevermind. MD5 is 989d1a6b16451a89b0318e20537b13ff  now I just have to find out if this matches anyone else's

Comment: I'd post mine, but I'm away from my media collection until next week. I can try and contact a colleague and post his hash if you'd like?

Comment: Not sure which ISO you have, but here's the md5 that I get for VS 2012 Pro a6a41004e420d62eb5093887b3fc3b04  (en_visual_studio_professional_2012_x86_dvd_920779.iso)

Comment: oh sorry, I have VS2012 Ultimate.  @Crippledsmurf, that would be great

Comment: The person I thought had Ultimate only had Pro. Unfortunately this is also the edition I have. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: You can see the SHA1 checksums on MSDN subscriber downloads if you view the download details - 6A2B87BCD336A96AC39CF85348E93E5AF45588EB (en_visual_studio_ultimate_2012_x86_dvd_920947.iso). Sorry they don't have the MD5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downloaded the web installer, and that seemed to work.  It seems that the iso was corrupted as the MD5 did not match.