# visual studio 2012 setup failed

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to install visual studio 2012 on win 7 enterprise sp1 from iso image. I got the following list of errors:

1. Microsoft visual c++ 2012 x86 minimum runtime -11.0.507 cann't find the requested object
2. Microsoft visual c++ 2012 x86 additional runtime -11.0.507 cann't find the requested object
3. Microsoft visual c++ 2012 x86 debug runtime -11.0.507 cann't find the requested object
4. Microsoft visual c++ 2012 compilers cann't find the requested object

Thanks waiting for reply

Answer (score 0):

Check that your ISO image is not corrupted ([other people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146692/vs2012-error-on-setup-on-windows-8-visual-c-2012-x86-minimum-runtime-cannot) seem to have found that was their problem).